# How to get utf-8 character encoding in output from Frog R?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using the r package frogr (https://github.com/vanatteveldt/frogr/blob/master/R/frog.r) to split sentences and lemmatize words in Dutch. However, I encounter a problem with the character encoding of special characters (such as é or á).

When I use Frog in the interactive version on my terminal (https://languagemachines.github.io/frog/) with an example sentence ("Ik heb één kat"), the output is this:

```
frog> Ik heb één kat.
frog>
Processing... 'Ik heb één kat.'
frog-:Tue Jul  2 11:59:10 2019 process 1 sentences
frog-:Tue Jul  2 11:59:10 2019 done with sentence[1]
1       Ik      ik      [ik]    VNW(pers,pron,nomin,vol,1,ev)   0.999791        O       B-NP    2       su
2       heb     hebben  [heb]   WW(pv,tgw,ev)   0.999430        O       B-VP    6       cnj
3       één     een     [één]   TW(hoofd,prenom,stan)   0.971940        O       B-NP    4       det
4       kat     kat     [kat]   N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)     0.999633        O       I-NP    2       predc
5       .       .       [.]     LET()   1.000000        O       O       4       punct
```

This works perfectly: Here, the encoding of 'één' is as I want it to be (UTF-8).

Now, I want to use frogr (https://github.com/vanatteveldt/frogr/blob/master/R/frog.r), an R package that does the same thing in R. However, that doesn't seem to work.

for instance:

```r
library(frogr)

text = "Ik heb één kat."

tokens = call_frog(text, host="127.0.0.1", port=9090)
tokens
```

The output I get is:

```r
docid sent position    word   lemma     morph                           pos     prob ner chunk parse1 parse2 majorpos
1     1    1        1      Ik      ik      [ik] VNW(pers,pron,nomin,vol,1,ev) 0.999791   O  B-NP      2     su      VNW
2     1    1        2     heb  hebben     [heb]                 WW(pv,tgw,ev) 0.999430   O  B-VP      0   ROOT       WW
3     1    1        3 ï¿½ï¿½n ï¿½ï¿½n [ï¿½ï¿½n]             N(soort,mv,basis) 0.346899   O  B-NP      2   obj1        N
4     1    1        4     kat     kat     [kat]   N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan) 0.998077   O  I-NP      2     su        N
5     1    1        5       .       .       [.]                         LET() 1.000000   O     O      4  punct      LET
```

Here, 'één' is outputted as 'ï¿½ï¿½n', whereas I want it to be outputted like 'één'.

As you can see above, I've already tried a way to get UTF-8 encoding inside R:

```r
text = iconv(text, "latin1", "UTF-8")
```

So that does not seem to be the problem.

The output that I get when not using R (i.e. in the terminal) is also in UTF-8 encoding.

It seems that this is a problem within this R package 'frogr'. How can I get UTF-8 encoding in the output from frogr?